# "Barking up the wrong tree" <- What does "bark" refer to here?

Tags: meaning, idioms

In the well-known idiom *to bark up the wrong tree*, what is the underlying metaphor? In particular what is the meaning of the verb *bark* here?

Being a native speaker, I fully understand the normal meanings of the verb *bark* relating to making a loud animal-like noise. However, this does not intuitively seem to be the meaning of the word in this idiom to me. Obviously, there is also the issue of the fact that *bark* also appears on trees, so I wonder if to *bark* up a tree is to shimmy up a tree by gripping onto its bark. I have no idea. I haven't been able to find any definitions of the verb *bark* that don't relate to making a noise.

Is to *bark up* something really just to make dog noises upwards towards it?

Any answers with references/sources greatly appreciated.

---

Here are the definitions of *bark* from [Oxford Dictionaries Online](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/bark)

> **bark**
>
> verb
>
> 1. [no object] (of a dog, fox, or seal) give a bark:
>
>    > ‘*a dog barked at her*’
>
>    1.1 (of a person) make a sound resembling a bark:
>
>    > ‘*she barked with laughter*’
>
>    2 [with object] Utter (a command or question) abruptly or aggressively:
>
>    > ‘ *he began barking out his orders*’
>    >
>    > > [with direct speech] ‘*Nobody is allowed up here*,’ *he barked.*
>
>    2.1 US [no object] Call out in order to sell or advertise something:
>
>    > ‘*doormen bark at passers-by, promising hot girls and cold beer*’

Comment: I'd always assumed it had to do with hunting - particularly prey that could climb trees.

Comment: Hi Araucaria, a google or similar search will reveal all. (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barking_up_the_wrong_tree) The expression alludes to a hunting dog barking at the base of one tree for prey that has sought refuge in another.

Comment: @RonaldSole I wouldn't normally go to Wikipedia for my  info, but I'll make an exception here. If you put that in an answer with a bit more detail, I'll upvote it and accept it.

Comment: @user888379 Yes, your suggestion seems to be supported by Wikipedia, see RS's comment above.

Comment: Check out the use of *tree* as a verb. Generally, dogs can't climb trees, so once they "tree" their prey, all they can do is sit at the base of the tree and bark up at the animal.

Comment: @deadrat I learn some new vocab every day round here ... I don't do well with tree vocab. We don't have trees on my island  ... :) No kidding, it's true.

Comment: @Araucaria So you're from… St. Kilda? Iceland? Svalbard?

Comment: @Araucaria Given Josh's well-researched and comprehensive answer, may I decline with thanks.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet St Kilda's the nearest ... Pretty close in fact.

Comment: Not even a single acyclic connected graph?

Comment: @deadrat Not on *my* island! (that's a joke, before anyone has a go at me ...)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of evidence of research. Phrase Finder is the obvious place to start here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I have never heard of Phrase Finder. I'm not sure that what is a commonly available resource for  someone who has been hanging around on EL&U for five years reading idiom questions is a general resource for the normal reading public. As far as research goes, I checked lots of dictionaries, as mentioned - citing them would have done nothing to improve the question here.

Comment: @Araucaria It's mentioned in the list of works that may be regarded as general reference [here on Meta](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available). We are still, I hope, a website for linguists. There are many, many others where standards are rightly not so demanding.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth That isn't a list of general reference guides at all!!!! That's a list of GOOD RESOURCES. It inlcudes McCawley, CamGEL, OED amongt others. If you don't have a subscription to OED, for example, you cannot reference it. If you don't have £250 you can't buy CmGEL. If you don't have a degree in linguistics and a year to ead it McCawley's useless too. But I'm sure you know that that's not a list of general refence resources in the first place.

Comment: The question there includes 'Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic.' Which informs the request. As I'm sure you know.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Yep, commonly-available does not just mean freely available, as I'm sure you understand.

Comment: There's an old story about a guy who tried to build a birch-bark canoe in the classic Native American way. He followed all the steps correctly except that he accidentally used a sycamore instead of a birch as his source tree. But that was enough: the minute he stepped into the canoe it broke apart and sank. When he asked his friend what went wrong, the friend said, "I guess you were barking up the wrong tree."

Comment: -1 no research....

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've always understood the meaning of ***[bark](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bark)*** to refer the noise produced by dogs. Etymonline appears to confirm this:

> - in reference to a dog sound, Old English beorcan "to bark," from Proto-Germanic *berkan (source also of Old Norse berkja "to bark"), of echoic origin. Related: Barked; barking. ***To bark up the wrong tree is U.S. colloquial, first attested 1832, from notion of hounds following the wrong scent.***

***[The Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/56150.html)*** appears to be on the same page:

> ***The allusion is to hunting dogs barking at the bottom of trees where they mistakenly think their quarry is hiding.***
>
> The earliest known printed citation is in James Kirke Paulding's *Westward Ho!*, 1832:
>
> - "*Here he made a note in his book, and I begun to smoke him for one of those fellows that drive a sort of a trade of making books about old Kentuck and the western country: **so I thought I'd set him barking up the wrong tree a little,** and I told him some stories that were enough to set the Mississippi a-fire; but he put them all down in his book.*"
>
> ***The phrase must have caught on in the USA quickly after Hall's book. It appeared in several American newspapers throughout the 1830s***; for example, this piece from the Gettysburg newspaper *The Adams Sentinel*, March 1834:
>
> - *"Gineral you are barkin' up the wrong tree this time, for I jest see that rackoon jump to the next tree, and afore this he is a mile off in the woods.*

According to ***[WOOFipedia](http://www.woofipedia.com/articles/where-does-the-expression-barking-up-the-wrong-tree-come-from)*** (www.woofipedia.com), the expression derives from the practice of hunting raccoons with trained hounds:

> - ***Settlers of the American wilderness depended on the raccoon as a steady source of meat, fur, and fat.*** Frontiersmen bred uniquely American hounds that specialized in tracking and treeing the nocturnal carnivore. Coonhounds pursue their quarry through woods and swamps until the raccoon scoots up a tree. They then bay and bawl loudly to indicate their location. ***Sometimes, though, the wily raccoon fools its pursuers and the hounds literally bark up the wrong tree.***

Just a bit of year-end fun:

[image] 
(lowres.cartoonstock.com)

Comment: woof! If you've ever seen a dog run around a tree barking after chasing a cat up the tree you know exactly what barking up a tree is :)